# Return SSRS PDF From Java Spring Boot REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I understand how to call an `SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services)` PDF report through a URL from an Angular web app but what I'm trying to do is call our app's Java Spring Boot REST API to fetch the SSRS report instead.  We'd like to do this because we have an iOS app (and other apps coming) that use our REST API and would like to retrieve this SSRS PDF report also.  Additionally, the Java fetches some data from other microservices to pass on to the SSRS report as parameters, so it makes sense to centralize the generation of this report in our REST API.

My question is

> how to do this in Java Spring Boot?

I can't find much online on how to achieve this.  Our REST API is also running in a Linux cloud environment. So we'd need to provide authentication of some kind for a Windows user I'd image.  The best I can find online is this and I'm wondering if this could be the right approach?

> https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/authenticator/access-password-protected-url-with-authenticator/